# How can I match square bracket in Regex Scala?

Tags: scala

I am trying to match `[`and `]`. 
but the when we also use the two for regular expression, 
how can I write some pattern to match the two brackets?
Using `\[` does not work as it gives out compiler error for the following line:

```
 regex(new Regex("([^.#; \\t\\r\n(){}\[\]',`\"][^; \\t\\r\\n(){}\[\]',`\"]*|[.][^; \\t\\r\\n(){}\[\]',`\"]+)"))
```

Comment: hmmm.. it seems that using double backslash works....

Comment: Two tips - first, consider using triple quoted strings so you don't need to escape backslashes; second, you can call .r on a string to turn it in to a Regex.  Putting these together, you can do: val MajorMinor: Regex = """(\d+)\.(\d+)""".r

Comment: @mpilquist Why didn't you post it as answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go with

```
"""\[[^\]]+\]""".r
```

for the Regex.

```
"""\[[^\]]+\]""".r findAllIn """[a], [b], [123 Hello]""" toList
res2: List[String] = List([a], [b], [123 Hello])
```

The Regex would work fine as long as you won't need to parse nested expressions as in

```
"""\[[^\]]+\]""".r findAllIn """[[a], [b]]""" toList
res4: List[String] = List([[a], [b])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val Bracketed = """\[.*?\]""".r

def check(s: String) =
  (Bracketed findAllIn s).toSeq

check("Wrong (curved) thingies") // Nil
check("") // Nil
check("[Hi]") // [Hi]
check("[Hi][There]") // [Hi], [There]
check("[Hi]gap[There]gop") // [Hi], [There]
```